# Gradient descent with random input implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement gradient descent on a dataset. Even though I tried everything, I couldn't make it work. So, I created a test case. I am trying my code on a random data and try to debug.

More specifically, what I am doing is, I am generating random vectors between 0-1 and random labels for these vectors. And try to over-fit the training data.

However, my weight vector gets bigger and bigger in each iteration. And then, I have infinities. So, I do not actually learn anything. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def getRandomVector(n):
   return np.random.uniform(0,1,n)

def getVectors(m, n):
   return [getRandomVector(n) for i in range(n)]

def getLabels(n):
   return [random.choice([-1,1]) for i in range(n)]

def GDLearn(vectors, labels):
   maxIterations = 100
   stepSize = 0.01

   w = np.zeros(len(vectors[0])+1)
   for i in range(maxIterations):
      deltaw = np.zeros(len(vectors[0])+1)
      for i in range(len(vectors)):
         temp = np.append(vectors[i], -1)
         deltaw += ( labels[i] - np.dot(w, temp) ) * temp
      w = w + ( stepSize * (-1 * deltaw) )
   return w

vectors = getVectors(100, 30)
labels = getLabels(100)

w = GDLearn(vectors, labels)
print w
```

I am using LMS for loss function. So, in all iterations, my update is the following,

[image]

where w^i is the ith weight vector and R is the stepSize and E(w^i) is the loss function.

Here is my loss function. (LMS)

[image]

and here is how I derivated the loss function,

[image],

Now, my questions are:

1. Should I expect good results in this random scenario using Gradient Descent? (What is the theoretical bounds?)
2. If yes, what is my bug in my implementation?

PS: I tried several other `maxIterations` and `stepSize` parameters. Still not working.
PS2: This is the best way I can ask the question here. Sorry if the question is too specific. But it made me crazy. I really want to learn the problem.

Comment: your code has obvious errors. I will reply in a post shortly.

Comment: I was having a missing minus somewhere. Problem is solved. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of faults:

- In `GetVectors()` method, you did not actually use the input variable `m`;
- In `GDLearn()` method, you have a double loop, but you use the same variable `i` as the loop variables in both loops. (I guess the logic is still right, but it's confusing).
- The prediction error (`labels[i] - np.dot(w, temp)`) has the wrong sign.
- Step size does matters. If I am using 0.01 as step size, the cost is increasing in each iteration. Changing it to be 0.001 solved the problem.

Here is my revised code based on your original code.

> ```
> import numpy as np
> import random
>
> def getRandomVector(n):
>    return np.random.uniform(0,1,n)
>
> def getVectors(m, n):
>    return [getRandomVector(n) for i in range(m)]
>
> def getLabels(n):
>    return [random.choice([-1,1]) for i in range(n)]
>
> def GDLearn(vectors, labels):
>    maxIterations = 100
>    stepSize = 0.001
>
>    w = np.zeros(len(vectors[0])+1)
>    for iter in range(maxIterations):
>       cost = 0
>       deltaw = np.zeros(len(vectors[0])+1)
>       for i in range(len(vectors)):
>          temp = np.append(vectors[i], -1)
>          prediction_error = np.dot(w, temp) - labels[i]
>          deltaw += prediction_error * temp
>          cost += prediction_error**2
>       w = w -  stepSize * deltaw
>       print 'cost at', iter, '=', cost
>    return w
>
> vectors = getVectors(100, 30)
> labels = getLabels(100)
>
> w = GDLearn(vectors, labels)
> print w
> ```

Running result -- you can see the cost is decreasing with each iteration but with a diminishing return.

```
cost at 0 = 100.0
cost at 1 = 99.4114482617
cost at 2 = 98.8476022685
cost at 3 = 98.2977744556
cost at 4 = 97.7612851154
cost at 5 = 97.2377571222
cost at 6 = 96.7268325883
cost at 7 = 96.2281642899
cost at 8 = 95.7414151147
cost at 9 = 95.2662577529
cost at 10 = 94.8023744037
......
cost at 90 = 77.367904046
cost at 91 = 77.2744249433
cost at 92 = 77.1823702888
cost at 93 = 77.0917090883
cost at 94 = 77.0024111475
cost at 95 = 76.9144470493
cost at 96 = 76.8277881325
cost at 97 = 76.7424064707
cost at 98 = 76.6582748518
cost at 99 = 76.5753667579
[ 0.16232142 -0.2425511   0.35740632  0.22548442  0.03963853  0.19595213
  0.20080207 -0.3921798  -0.0238925   0.13097533 -0.1148932  -0.10077534
  0.00307595 -0.30111942 -0.17924479 -0.03838637 -0.23938181  0.1384443
  0.22929163 -0.0132466   0.03325976 -0.31489526  0.17468025  0.01351012
 -0.25926117  0.09444201  0.07637793 -0.05940019  0.20961315  0.08491858
  0.07438357]
```